# Why is my flutter app crashing in release mode and working fine in debug mode?

Tags: flutter, debugging, build, release, vosk

I am currently developing a voice assisted flutter app using `vosk` and the `vosk-flutter-plugin` linked below.

https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-flutter

The app works completely fine in `debug mode` but crashes upon opening the view that accesses the `vosk-plugin`. It doesn't crash on startup, it crashes only on that specific view. Specifically it crashes when the `vosk-flutter-plugin` tries to initialize the `vosk` language model, that is loaded from a downloaded zip file.

The console displays the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24895): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
E/AndroidRuntime(24895): Process: com.example.app, PID: 24895
E/AndroidRuntime(24895): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't obtain peer field ID for class com.sun.jna.Pointer
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at com.sun.jna.Native.initIDs(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Unknown Source:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at com.sun.jna.Native.H(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at org.vosk.LibVosk.<clinit>(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at org.vosk.Model.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at u1.b$d.a(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at u1.b$d.call(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at u1.c$b.run(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
E/AndroidRuntime(24895):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

My guess is that it is caused by the flutter code obscuration in the release mode somehow.

Using the `--no-shrink` command when building the `apk` doesn't work though.
(Also that flag doesn't exist in the `flutter build appbundle` command)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer when I don't see any code.
But this happened to me and it was related to the **expanded** widget (I used it **in stack widget**), and when I refactor the code, it did not crash in the release mode.

Comment: how did you found out? what did you used to track the error?